# Adding application in Noteworthy and From Your Organization in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Is there a way I can add/remove custom application or document library or list to Noteworthy section and From Your Organization section.

[image]

Comment: do u want another in this section...like 2 OOTB and you want more?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Sorry for the confusion. I would like to add an application on the right-hand side of the menu "From Your Organization". Also, there is a section called "Noteworthy " when you click on "Apps You Can Add" where I would like to add more items. By default, it shows "Document Library", "Custom List" and "Tasks".